# Configure python keyring to save passwords in a user-defined keyring

Tags: python, keyrings

I installed python-keyring (Version: 15.1.0-1) (Ubuntu 18.10) via `apt` and I am able to add new password entries issuing a command like

`keyring set myservice user1`

When opening the 'Passwords and Keys' app I can see the new key added to the 'Login' keyring:

[image: passwords_keys]

However, I already have a lot of keys that were automatically added for me by installed programs. I would like to keep these new keys I'm creating manually in a separate keyring, for easier management - let's say in the 'fancy_keyring' I created.

Reading up on https://pypi.org/project/keyring/ , I tried taking advantage of the `default-keyring` option set in the file keyringrc.cfg. The file doesn't exist (neither does the directory indicated by running the python commands in this section of the page https://pypi.org/project/keyring/#id9). But by creating the path indicated by those commands and the file keyringrc.cfg I was able to *break* the `keyring` command, resulting in errors such as

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'login'
```

or

```
AttributeError: module 'keyring' has no attribute 'myservice'
```

because I wasn't able to figure out how to correctly point to the new keyring in the keyringrc.cfg file I created,

```
[backend]
default-keyring=fancy_keyring.keyring
keyring-path=/home/user/.local/share/keyrings
```

The path `/home/user/.local/share/keyrings` is where Ubuntu places the file fancy_keyring.keyring that is created via the 'Passwords and Keys' GUI.

So I don't know how to properly setup this keyringrc.cfg file.
Is it possible to have the keyring command save passwords in a user-defined keyring and how would that be acomplished?